# What is with absouletly random upvotes?

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

One various non-answer that were delted I have seen upvotes. Why? Is there soemting that we can do about this?

Comment: Oops. If someone could make voting and votes tag synonyms, that would be great.

Comment: Have you considered turning on spell-checking in your browser? It's hard to take you seriously when you have three spelling mistakes (as well as grammar errors) in four sentences.

Comment: The purpose of this site is not spelling. If you understand idea then the nitty picky spelling doesnt matter. @OrganicMarble

Comment: If you want to continue to come across as a junior high dropout, press on. As a hiring manager and working engineer for a NASA contractor for many years, if you think how you come across in written communication does not reflect on how you are perceived technically, you are sadly mistaken.

Comment: I am not trying to get a NASA job right now, I am trying to get an idea across on more informal meta. @OrganicMarble

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once an answer is deleted, it cannot be voted on, so the votes must have been applied before its deletion. There is nothing we can do about that.

Any reputation the poster gained is nullified when the post is deleted.

Comment: How about non-deleted posts @called2voyage

Comment: If a post hasn't been deleted yet, I don't see any reason why we should be concerned about votes. There will always be differences in opinion about the quality of an answer, and while sometimes a vote may not be merited that is expected behavior.

Comment: there are non-answers that remain for years which for some reason have a bunch of upvotes. @called2voyage

Comment: If they're truly non-answers, they can be flagged for deletion.

Comment: It takes years, many of my post flags are nonanswers that have remained for a while. There still remain proabbly hundreds. @called2voyage

Comment: That's ok. These are a relatively low impact part of the system. If there's an urgent reason for removal, they will be cleaned up.